# React - CORS issue No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, cors, react-redux

I am building a React app to scrape content from a site through server and get that data and display it on the client side.

I am web-scraping content from a site in server.js.

I am trying to get that data through axios call in app.js in the client side.

However, I am getting this CORS error, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

Could you please help me fix this issue?

Here is my server.js :

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/news/:newsName', function(req, res) {
  var data = "";

  const techCrunchURL = "https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/04/nsa-triples-metadata-collection-numbers-sucking-up-over-500-million-call-records-in-2017/";

  var techCrunchNewsItems = {
    bodyOne: '',
    bodyTwo: ''
  };

  switch(req.params.newsName) {
    case 'tech-crunch':

      request(techCrunchURL, function(err, response, html) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        if($('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text().split(' ').length > 50) {
          techCrunchNewsItems.bodyOne = $('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text();
        } else {
          techCrunchNewsItems.bodyOne = $('.article-content').children('p').eq(0).text();
          techCrunchNewsItems.bodyTwo = $('.article-content').children('p').eq(1).text();
        }
          
        data = techCrunchNewsItems;

        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      });

      break;

    default:
      data = 'Please type in correct news source';
      break;
  }
});

var server = app.listen(8082, function () {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Here is my app.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../css/style.css';

export default class Hello extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.techCrunchNewsDate = '';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8082/news/tech-crunch`)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;

        this.techCrunchNewsDate = data;
      });
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.techCrunchNewsDate);

    return (
      <div>
        Hello from react
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Add this to your chrome browser and Toggle it to green

Comment: no, that fixed chrome browser only - that isn't an answer @HarishSoni - that's a lazy hack :p

Comment: fix the server side using [expressjs cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` before `res.send()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React issue, it's a general issue with any JS-based app. The resource you are attempting to scrape is what is causing this, not your code.

If you haven't already read it, read this: [MDN CORS Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)